# Is it true, if there is no surjection of A onto B, then there must be injection A onto B??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A is any set.
If there is no surjection of A onto B, then there must be injection A onto B.

Is it true?? if so give me the proof, please.

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you heard about the axiom of choice?

Comment: i have no idea. In Cantor's theorem, P(A) is larger than A, i thought that larger may mean that there must be left in P(A), when one to one map from A onto P(A).

Comment: So i wonder no surjection assure injection.

Comment: i have no idea. In Cantor's theorem, P(A) is larger than A, i thought that larger may mean that there must be left in P(A), when one to one map from A onto P(A). To say P(A) is larger than A, i think, it is needed that there is injection from A to P(A). In this case it is true, but i wonder it is accepted in general case.
So i wonder no surjection assure injection

Comment: i haven't heard axiom of choice.

Comment: @마재화 Do you assume that $A$ and $B$ are finite? (If so add that to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked is obviously no, because an injection of $A$  onto $B$ is surjective; that's what "onto" means. You meant to ask this:

> > If there is no surjection of $A$ onto $B$ must there exist an injection from $A$ into $B$?

The answer to *that* question is yes, assuming the Axiom of Choice: Let $M$ be the set of all ordered pairs $(F,f)$ such that $F\subset A$ and $f:F\to B$ is injective. Define a partial order on $M$ by saysing that $(F_1,f_1)\le(F_2,f_2)$ if $F_1\subset F_2$ and $f_2|_{F_1}=f_1$.

Zorn's Lemma shows that $M$ has a maximal element; now if $(F,f)$ is maximal the fact that there is no surjection from $A$ onto $B$ shows that $F=A$.

Comment: Thanks for point out my fault, and your answer.!!!